# Find possible move for backgammon

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

[Find an possible moves in Backgammon games.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backgammon)

I written an brute force approach which can detect possible moves.

1. Added an dices value into turn player checker

   ```
   // let possibleMoves: number[];
     let possibleMoves = [];
     let possibleMoveDice =[];
     for(let dice of dices){
       for(let entry of p1){
           let num = entry + dice;
           if(num < 24){
               possibleMoves.push(num);
           }
       }

     possibleMoveDice.push(possibleMoves);
     //Make possible move blank
     possibleMoves=[];

     }
   ```
2. Compare this possible move with opponent checker if opponent checker
   more than one in pile than this possible move should excluded.

   ```
   //Check available move with second checker
    for (let checker of possibleMoveDice) {
      for (let posMove of checker) {
        let count :number =0;
         for (let entry of p2) {
            if (posMove == entry) {
               count++;
               if(count > 1){
               //Remove from the possible moves
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   ```

> Time complexity of this algorithm quadratic but I am looking for algorithm
>   that use less time complexity.  If anyone have better approach or any
>   suggestion to improve in code it would be highly appreciate.

Comment: This isn't a correct implementation. There's rules about the bar (if you have men on the bar, you must play them first), rolling doublets (66, 55, ..., 11), bearing-off rules, a rule about playing both dice if possible (and the larger if only one of the dice is usable). All these make the solution quite fiddly.

Comment: Yes you are right I did not add double queue and bar logic over there . I have started implementation with baby step later I can add those data once it's complete.